# Very slow viewing the SQL Server Agent history

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a big problem with the SQL Server Agent history. it has become VERY VERY slow when i try to view it. If I try through Management Studio I often get a timeout and if I try viewing it with `sp_help_jobhistory` it is just running for a long time.

I tried reducing the history size and the `sysjobhistory` table has only 8000 rows....

Is there any way to optimize this somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that the sysjobhistiory table is not fragmented. The easiest thing to do is reindex it. Since the table is so small, the reindex should happen quickly.

Comment: that did the trick! thx

Comment: `ALTER INDEX ALL ON msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory REBUILD`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to more regularly cycle (start new) your agent log. That can be done with `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_cycle_agent_errorlog;` . Perform this periodically and your logs will remain both smaller and more manageable. (I generally create an Agent job that cycles the log weekly.) BTW, you can also cycle the error log as well with `EXEC master.sys.sp_cycle_errorlog;`.

Comment: good idea.... i do it already on the error log